# Qtcreator c++ on Centos 7

Tags: c++, qt, centos, 64-bit, qt-creator

```
edit :I resolved error due to package missing
```

I have installed  Qt Creator 4.1.0 using yum on centos 7 64 bit.

qt versionQt 5.6.1
cpp library GCC 4.8.5 20150623

I run simple application

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
qDebug() << "Hello World";
    return a.exec();
}
```

but it gives:

> c++ CONFIG.H FILE/FOLDER NOT FOUND

So to solve problem I have copied all cpp header file s(/usr/includes/c++/4.8.2/bits/) to project folder.

I am beginner to qt.

Edit Answer:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
 yum install mesa-libGL-devel 
 yum install qt qt-creator 
 yum install mesa-libGL-devel 
 yum install libstdc++-devel
```

Comment: Do not copy anything. Replace `<QtCore/QCoreApplication>` with `<QCoreApplication>` and try building the project again. Also tell us what's in your `.pro` file

Comment: my .pro file is `QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = demo3
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp`

Comment: Please reply to comments asking for clarification by fixing the question by editing it, not by commenting.

Comment: actually my problem solved. its because i have not installed packages. `yum groupinstall "Development Tools" <br/>
  yum install mesa-libGL-devel <br/>
  yum install qt qt-creator <br/>
 yum install mesa-libGL-devel <br/> yum install  libstdc++-devel`